# Storing references on structures and deserializing them

Tags: rust, reference, reference-type, owned-types

I am parsing a toml config file and retrieve it's content into some structs, using `serde` and `toml`.

So, a config structure could be defined like:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Config<'a> {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    pub server: Inner<'a>
}
```

and another related:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Inner<'a> {
    pub iprop1: &'a str,
    pub iprop2: &'a str,
}
```

This is the pub interface exposed for loading the config:

```
pub fn load() -> Config<'static> {

    let config_file: String = fs::read_to_string(CONFIG_FILE_IDENTIFIER)
        .expect("Error opening or reading the configuration file");

    toml::from_str(config_file.as_str())
        .expect("Error generating the configuration")
}
```

So, the issue it's clear. I can return data owned by the `load()` function.

I could change all the `&str` refereneces to `String`, because I am not able to fully comprehend how to properly play with references in Rust, but I would like to know, if there's another way to validate those references with lifetimes in Rust, so my structs can start to hold references instead owned values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

References refer to data owned elsewhere.  For this to work, the data being referred to must live at least as long as the reference, otherwise you have a reference to data that no longer exists.

In your `load()` function, the return type declares that `Config` will borrow data that is `'static`.  This is a special lifetime that refers to data that is valid for the entire lifetime of the program.

However, `toml::from_str()` here borrows from `config_file`, which does *not* live for the entire lifetime of the program.  It lives only until `load()` returns.  You are attempting to return a reference to data owned by a function local, which is impossible, because the data will be destroyed before the returned reference can ever be used.

If there is nowhere else for `config_file` to live, the data should indeed be owned by the `Config` structure.  The way you express that is by using `String` instead of `&str` within that structure.

Comment: what about to return the data from the `load()` function as a Box<Config>? Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @AlexVergara No, then you'll just have a boxed struct that still references something elsewhere. A boxed reference is still a reference.

Comment: thanks for the last clarification. I solved the issue moving the returned code from the load() function to an outher scope where it lives enought to borrow the content.
Also, I was thinking to store it as a static lazy ref, instead of returning the struct with the references, but dunno how idiomatic could be that approach

Comment: @AlexVergara Lazy-initialized statics usually still have a lifetime due to the `Deref` wrapper, though you could unsafe-cast the reference to `'static` safely.